# cannot import module I created in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I can't figure out why this import is failing. I have tried everything I can think of, changed the export and import to every single tutorial I can find online, and every single time it fails. Theoretically this should be very simple....

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import config from './config'

//rest of my code here...
```

config.js

```
const config = {
  url: "my url string here",
  port: 5000,
  callbackURL: "another url here"
}
export default config
```

in my package.json file I do have `"type": "module"` in there and all the imports from the node modules work just fine, it just fails on the config import. When I try to run the code above I get...

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '{path}/config' imported from '{path}/server.js... Did you mean to import ..config.js?
```

But there is no ../config.js, both server.js and config.js are in the same directory

I figured this should be something easy, I just need to import a module that I am creating, but nothing works, it always tells me if can't find the module config. I've tried changing the name thinking maybe config was reserved. So I changed to settings.js, same thing, Cannot find module settings.
I've tried changing the export to numerous ways, stuff like...
config.js

```
const config = {
  url: "my urls",
  port: 5000,
  callbackURL: "another"
}
export { config }
```

then changing my import to `import { config } from './config'`. Same thing. I've tried removing the `./` in front of config, same thing.

Just for extra information here is my actual package.json...

```
{
  "name": "my_test_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

And I am trying to run it with `npm start` in terminal

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says to add .js at the end in your import statement.

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '{path}/config' imported from '{path}/server.js... Did you mean to import ..config.js?
```

Use

```
import config from "./config.js"
```

if you are using `export {config}` then

```
import {config} from "./config.js"
```

Comment: Some readers may not notice the difference with OP's code. Please consider adding some explanation to make it explicit.